# AS3: How will I find movieclips name of external swf which is loaded inside a movieclip.movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, load, loader, movieclip, addchild

I've loaded a swf inside a movieclip which is inside another movieclip.

> **frame**.**pageLoader**.addChild(intoMC)

Here's the code:

```
 frame.visible = true;

var bookImagePath: String = "file://" + File.userDirectory.nativePath.toString() + "/Books/" + someFoldername + "/Home.swf";
trace(bookImagePath);



var intoMC: Loader = new Loader;

intoMC.load(new URLRequest(bookImagePath));

frame.pageLoader.addChild(intoMC)
```

Now, this Home.swf has some movieclips with random names(Ex: triger, boat, rain), which I want make as button.

Need help here...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "random names"? How are these names randomly assigned to the movie clips? Where are these movie clips places inside of `Home.swf`? And what do you mean by "I want make as button"? What "button" behavior are you expecting?

Comment: Yes these are the movie clips inside my swf file. And as you said, I want "button" behavior for these movieclips.

Comment: I'm asking you to *clarify* those things. Provide more details. What is the expected behavior and the expected result.

Comment: I've a interface, where I've a movieclip called frame, inside which I've another movieclip called pageLoader. Now I've different pages as different swf files, and first one as home page, this I am loading in frame.pageLoader, also my home page has some movieclips (ex. tiger, rain, etc). So when I click on tiger or any other movieclip, in frame.pageLoader another swf will load. Like if I click on "triger" movieclip it will load "tiger.swf". The problem I am facing is I am not able read those movieclips which are in my home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this.
And this worked.

```
var someMC: MovieClip

var intoMC: Loader = new Loader;

intoMC.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, PageLoad);

intoMC.load(new URLRequest(bookImagePath));


function PageLoad(e: Event): void {

    someMC = e.target.content as MovieClip;;

    displayFrame.pageLoader.addChild(intoMC)
}
```

Is there any other way?